# Why PS didn't saved informations in these txt files?

Tags: powershell

I didn't got any errors and powershell made these files, but they are empty. What did i wrong?

```
$Services = Get-Service
Foreach ($Proces in $Services) {
If($Proces.status -eq "running") { Out-File $Proces >> "C:\proces.txt"} 
If($Proces.status -eq "stopped") { Out-File $Proces >> "C:\proces2.txt"} 
}
```

Comment: `Out-File $Proces` actually write something to file `$Proces`, but you did not supply any content to write. `Out-File` do not produce any output, thus redirecting it to file with `>>` have no value. BTW, `>>` is just an alias to `Out-File -Append`.

Answer (score 1):

[`>>` is the append redirect operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1), which is basically the same as `Out-File -Append`. So it is like calling `Out-File` twice.

With the command `Out-File $Proces >> "C:\proces.txt"` you pass in no input object to `Out-File`. So you write a blank file to `$Proces`. Then take the output of that command (nothing) and write that to `C:\proces.txt`, which creates the second blank file.

So you will want to decide on using `Out-File -Append` or `>>`

Here is your code using just `Out-File`:

```
$Services = Get-Service
Foreach ($Service in $Services) {
    If ($Service.Status -eq "Running") { Out-File -InputObject $Service -Path "C:\proces.txt" -Append} 
    If ($Service.Status -eq "Stopped") { Out-File -InputObject $Service -Path "C:\proces2.txt" -Append } 
}
```

Here is your code using just `>>`:

```
$Services = Get-Service
Foreach ($Service in $Services) {
    If ($Service.Status -eq "Running") { $Service >> "C:\proces.txt" } 
    If ($Service.Status -eq "Stopped") { $Service >> "C:\proces2.txt" } 
}
```

There are many other ways to do what you are attempting

Here is a way using the `Where-Object` cmdlet rather than a loop/conditional

```
$Services = Get-Service 
$Services | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Out-File "C:\proces.txt" -Append
$Services | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"} | Out-File "C:\proces2.txt" -Append
```

Here is a way using the `.where()` method using split

```
$Running,$Stopped = (Get-Service).Where({$_.Status -eq 'Running'},'Split')
$Running | Out-File "C:\proces.txt" -Append
$Stopped | Out-File "C:\proces2.txt" -Append
```

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @dvmvnvq: Acceptance would be appreciable then.